# How to filter by id in a list with Sencha touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a list in Sencha Touch, and I need to get different records for each item list it is very important have in mind for each item list I have a button, showing in the inside of a modal window other list with the "templates" records.. (I will try to explain me with the code..)

```
  {
    "id" : "0100144200",
    "address" : "hello street,Hamm",
    "openSurveys" : 1,
    "type" : 0,
    "withSurveys" : true,
    "templates": {
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "0000000772",
          "name": "TEST GENERAL AV 1"
        },
        {
          "id": "0000000799",
          "name": "TEST_TEMPLATE2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am receiving this object for each item list, and I need to include in a modal window data included in the templates object.. How to detect in the list id number and related templates?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not 100% sure exactly what you want, I start with my assumption: you have a list and when tap on it you want to show the child templates in a floating, modal panel in maybe another list?

Here is a fiddle that uses hasMany association to read the child templates and the two lists: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11v5

The important piece is the `hasMany` config in the `Fiddle.model.Something` model. Then in the `itemtap` event of the main list, I get the templates from the association and simply show a floating list for the templates.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but maybe my description of the problem was not correct..   I have a list with different customers and one button with other child list related with the customer, for each item of the parent list, child list is different.. for this reason I need to get customer id from the parent list to filter correctly by id..  that is the scene, following your example I don´t have other model, I am playing with an object of templates, I need to get the record of the parent list and navigate to the nested object called "templates"  do you know what I mean?

Comment: Then what you have provided isn't clear enough. If you have a collection of the customer datas, then you can loop through them and check if the template you are looking for a matching customer is within each customer. In order to provide code, I'd rather have a sample of what you are doing maybe in the form of a Sencha Fiddle?

Comment: Thank you @Mitchell with your help and efforts from my side I have found the solution..